# Measure the pressure on a push button

Tags: button, pressure

I am looking for a way to measure the pressure on a push button when it is pressed. I intend to save it in flash of a microcontroller.

Please let me know if you know any device which could be useful.

Thanks,

Comment: You probably should use a pressure sensor for that.

Comment: Do you want the actual pressure (force per unit area), or just the total force? If the latter, the sensor you want is called a "strain gauge". But you need to be a lot more specific about what you need: the range of force (or pressure) you expect to see, the accuracy and sample rate (bandwidth) you require, and any other constraints imposed by the application.

Comment: I believe hall-effect buttons and switches give you some feedback about how hard or fast the button is pressed.

Comment: Wondering what pressure on a button has to do with flash in a micro....

Comment: Put your device on  a set of scales (as long as it is small / light enough), use the "tare" button and set to 0 (zero). Push on the button -gently increasing the pressure applied -  and read the result in your preferred units... This does depend on what accuracy you require...

Comment: I would attach the button to a beam with a [strain gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge).

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9673

Comment: It looks like you better tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I assume you want force, not pressure. The biggest ambiguity in your question is whether you want the device being tested to measure the force, or whether some kind of external test rig will be measuring the force. If external, then a strain gauge is the best way to go. If the device itself must detect the button press and store force, you may need to use a force sensing resistor + ADC input. That will be quite a bit more complicated than a typical tact switch button.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your replies. I found a suitable strain gauge and Force sensitive resistor as suggested by @Dave Tweed and Bruce Abbott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a force sensitive resistor like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9375).

[image]

Or perhaps a linear hall-effect push button like [this one](https://media.digikey.com/PDF/Data%20Sheets/APEM%20Components%20PDFs/IH_%20Series.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a rubber button with some 6mm airline pipe to a pressure sensor connected to microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If you know any manufacturer name, that has the product, could you let me know. I tried searching using keywords from your reply but could not find anything.

Comment: It will take some searching the simplest solution would be a pnuematic button such as in use on toilets some even look like simple buttons however pnuematic buttons do exist however you would have to come up with a solution to allow continuous use as once pressed any pressure would go to atmosphere, hydraulic buttons exist which may be suitable however costly if you really want a simple solution a plastic syringe some 5mm airline tubing and I would use the mpx2010dp differential pressure sensor which is cheap and readily available with a 5 volt output.

Comment: RS Components stock many of the items described a quick Google search will return many also ebay another source.

Answer (score 0):

This is such an awsome questions with many creative solutions!

- Use a coil-based button with spring,
- Measure hum.
- Based on mounting, use flex in pcb or hole with strain gauge.
- Body heat.

There must be tons of ways. Just add to the list.

Comment: Conductive foam button- more pressure less resistance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_sensor